# svn2git Does Not Fetch Branches or Tags

Tags: git, svn, migration, repository, svn2git

I am using [svn2git](https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git) to migrate an SVN repository of the standard branch/tag/trunk structure to Git. Having followed the instructions set forth by svn2git, I was able to fetch all of the revisions from SVN and have it translated into Git.

However, it did not include anything other than the trunk. Here is the structure of the SVN repo:

```
root
  |- branches
  |- tags
  |- trunk
```

and here is what SVN grabbed and translated into Git:

```
root
  ... list of project folders...
```

Everything was thrown into the master directory, no branches or tags were generated, as program had advertised. Also I'm sure that I am pointing svn2git to my root repo folder, and not just the trunk.

Does anyone know how to overcome this or perhaps know of a better alternative method to perform this translation?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Branches and tags in git is not shown in the file hierarchy, but in a separate namespace. Try the commands "git branch " and "git tag ", see what do you get?

Comment: Fantastic! I've got them all up on the Git server now. Thank you!